# Pays back or pays off?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Are these two phrasal verbs expressing the same concept or 'pays back ' has a certain negative connotation?

Comment: Hello Palolo. Have you looked in any of the online dictionaries?

Comment: I actually did but still was unclear to me!

Answer (score 3):

*Pay back* has two meanings, the first literal, *to make good on a loan by returning money to a lender* and the second figurative, *to exact vengeance*.

**I'll pay you back later today if you lend me $5 for lunch.

Some day, I'm going to pay you back for that insult.**

*Pay off* also has two meanings, the first, *to return money to a lender to completely satisfy a loan so that the borrower owes no more money*, and the second, *to bribe someone, such as a public official*.

**After thirty years, they had paid off the mortgage on their house.

They paid off the insurance inspector to keep quiet about the evidence of arson.**

Comment: Note that in the loan example you *pay off* the loan or mortgage, not the lender.

Answer (score 1):

The word *pay* in both expressions holds them very close together, but they have unique connotations

*[Pay off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+off)*:

> v.
>
> 1. To pay the full amount of some debt:
>      *She paid off the mortgage ahead of schedule.*
>      *He paid his college debt off six years after he graduated.*
> 2. To result in profit; be lucrative:
>      *Your efforts will eventually pay off.*
> 3. To result in some degree of profit or loss:
>      *My unwise bet paid off very badly.*
> 4. To pay the wages that are due to an employee upon discharge:
>      *We were fired, so they paid us off and we left the building.*
>      *The company didn't fire the workers because it couldn't afford to pay them off.*
> 5. To bribe someone in order to ensure cooperation:
>      *The owner of the factory paid off the inspectors so that they wouldn't report the safety violations.*
>      *I won't allow anyone to cheat here, and no one can pay me off.*
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs.

*[pay back](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+back)*:

> v.
>
> 1. To return some amount of money that has been borrowed:
>      *Will you pay back the $60 I gave you last month?*
>      *They finally paid the money back.*
> 2. To repay someone an amount of money:
>      *I might not have enough money to pay them back.*
>      *We need to pay back the bank.*
> 3. To reward or punish someone for something:
>      *After all their hard work, the team was paid back with a victory.*
>      *After they beat us, we paid them back by winning the series.*
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs.

To *pay off* tends to carry a focus on the **settlement of a deal**.
To *pay back* tends to carry a focus on the **debt or offense in the past**.

Both can have positive or negative connotations, depending on the context:

> - *We can **pay off** the loan six weeks early.*
> - *We can **pay back** the money in regular installments.*
> - *If you **pay off** the inspector, he may cut you some slack on your shoddy workmanship.*
> - *I'll **pay back** his insults by overlooking him when it's time for a promotion.*